# dispatchDraw goes on loop, Change visibility of view without calling dispatchDraw again

Tags: android, canvas, view, draw

I have custom ViewGroup with 2 child views, matched to parent, and one on another, one is front and one is behind. I wanted to cut out circle in front view so behind view would be visible in that circle.
I did it with `dispatchDraw`function, code is following:

```
 protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    System.out.println("dispatchDraw");
    views.get(1).setVisibility(GONE);        //views variable is list of child views
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    Path pathHole = new Path();
    pathHole.addCircle(touchPos[0], touchPos[1], 100, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(pathHole, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    views.get(1).setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

Basically what I did is hide front view and draw the ViewGroup (it drew only behind view),then I cut a circle path, set Visibility of front view and redraw again.
Here is the result:
[image: result]

Problem is `dispatchDraw` function goes on the loop because `.setVisibility()` calls this `dispatchDraw` again. 
How to fix this problem or what would be the better approach of this result?

Answer (score 0):

I managed same result with `view.draw(canvas);` function. Instead of adding views on ViewGroup I saved them in ListArray. then in `dispatchDraw` did following:

```
 protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    System.out.println("dispatchDraw");
    views.get(0).measure(canvas.getClipBounds().width(), canvas.getClipBounds().height());
    views.get(0).layout(0, 0, canvas.getClipBounds().width(), canvas.getClipBounds().height());
    views.get(0).draw(canvas);
    Path pathHole = new Path();
    pathHole.addCircle(touchPos[0], touchPos[1], 100, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(pathHole, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    views.get(1).measure(canvas.getClipBounds().width(), canvas.getClipBounds().height());
    views.get(1).layout(0, 0, canvas.getClipBounds().width(), canvas.getClipBounds().height());
    views.get(1).draw(canvas);   
}
```

I tried this before, but I did not know that `.draw(canvas)` does not work without `.measure()` and `.layout()` functions, if it has not parent and is not visible already.